# Cannot reinitialise DataTable error in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery code to fill table with json data. When I am clicking search button more than once it gives me the error:

> Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

I tried many methods but I can't resolve it. Can anyone help me?

```
<script>

function getData(){
    var URL_PREFIX="http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO:";
    var URL_MIDDLE="AND PackName:";
    var URL_SUFFIX="AND DocType:";
    var strSO="\"" + $("#ngramBoxstrSO").val() + "\"";
    var PackName="\"" + $("#ngramBoxPackName").val() + "\"";
    var DocType="\"" + $("#ngramBoxDocType").val() +"\"";
    var URL=URL_PREFIX + strSO + URL_MIDDLE + PackName + URL_SUFFIX + DocType;
    $.ajax({
        url:URL,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        jsonp : 'json.wrf',
        type :'get',
        cache :false,
        success: function(data){
            var docs=JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
            var jsonData=JSON.parse(docs);
            var html='';

            $.each(jsonData,function(key,value){
                html+='<tr>';
                html+='<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.strSO+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.PackName+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.DocType+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.DocName+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center"><button id="'+value.FilePath+""+'type="button onclick="openDocument(this.id)" class="btn btn-sm" >OPEN</td>';
                html+='</tr>';
            });
            $("#tbody").append(html);
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "aaSorting" : [],
                });
            })
        },

    });

}
</script>
```

Comment: When and how are you invoking `getData` method.

Comment: probably you are initializing datatable twice. Once on page is loading and once again when you are adding data to it. You need to do it only once.

Comment: @GaganDeep i have 3 textbox and i am querying value of them. for example i fill 1 textbox and i clicked search button. it gets the query result. but when i want to querying second time -for example fill all textbox- it gives me this error. `getData` method running when search button clicking

Comment: ok So what what you need to do is destroy the previous dataTable using `$('#example').DataTable().destroy();` first and then create again. Try it.

Comment: Also remove that `$(document).ready` function from inside the ajax call. there is no point keeping it there.

Comment: @GaganDeep i tried it so the error is gone but when i am clicking search button to querying again table is not refreshing.

Comment: destroy the DataTable before appending the data. then append then create again.

Comment: You may use if (!$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#example')) { $('#example').destroy() } prev to init function

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt work. when i am clicking search button more than once its add the new data after last row. for example the first clicking gets 53 results after second clicking it becomes 67 result but it must be 14 results